# Reloading an animation React-native-animatable library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-animatable

guy's I'm using the react-native-animatable library. Basically, when I load my app the animation runs, however, when I go to another tab and return to the initial page the animation doesn't run anymore. I think it's because it' doesn't get reloaded anymore and I was wondering how to reload a component. As you can see the View has an animation prop which is the animation which has to be loaded.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Button, StyleSheet, Image, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import {Fonts} from '../components/Fonts';
import { createAnimatableComponent, View, } from 'react-native-animatable';


class Home extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

               <View animation='bounceInLeft'    
               style={styles.container1}>

                    <View style={styles.card1}>


                                <ImageBackground 
                                source={require('../images/pictures/runop.jpg')} 
                                style={{width:'100%', height:200, }}>


                                    <Text
                                        style={{fontSize:30, alignSelf:'center', color:'white',
                                        fontFamily:Fonts.Nunito}}
                                        > Sport Schema's</Text>

                                </ImageBackground>

                   </View>

               </View>


               <View animation='bounceInRight'  style={styles.container2}>

                    <View style={styles.card2}>
                        <Image 
                            source={require('../images/pictures/foodop.jpg')} 
                            style={{width:'100%', height:200}}/>   

                    </View>

               </View>

               <View animation='bounceInLeft'  style={styles.container3}>

                    <View style={styles.card3}>
                        <Image 
                            source={require('../images/pictures/blogop.jpg')} 
                            style={{width:'100%', height:200}}/>   

                    </View>

               </View>   

            </View>

        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-navigation`, below solution might work for you.

Create a function which would start the animation after some milliseconds and pass it to the next screen as params. Example,

**SCREEN A**

```
animateFunction() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // start your animation
  }, 100);
}
```

`navigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAME, { startPrevScreenAnimation: animateFunction });`

And in the next screen call that function when the component unmounts (`componentWillUnmount()`). Example,

**SCREEN B**

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.navigation.state.params.startPrevScreenAnimation();
}
```

I said some milliseconds because you would want the animation to start once the screen transition is complete.

**OR**

Add a listener to your screen which fires an event when the screen is in focus.

```
if (this.props.navigation) {
  this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    () => { // Run your animation },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I eventually got it to work with a different method.
I used the withNavigationFocus from react-navigation to get the isFocused props of the current screen. Then i just used an if statement if screen is focused then run animation else dont.

import {withNavigationFocus} from 'react-navigation';

class Profile extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}        
render()
```

// This checks if current screen is focused then run the animation otherwise dont.

```
{

    if (this.props.isFocused && this.animation) {
        this.animation.bounce(800)
     }

    return (
        <View ref={(ref) =>  {this.animation = ref;}}

        style={styles.container3}>

            <View style={styles.card3}>
            <Text> hii</Text>

            </View>
        </View>

    );

}
```

}

});
export default withNavigationFocus(Profile);  // <- dont forget this!!